# Reducer gets triggered but subscribe function not fetching the change [React-Redux]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

`reducer` shows that I've received `doc` data from Firestore. `docStore.subscribe` is listening, but is not updating with latest `doc` data.

Expected outcome: upon page load, will get `docId` from URL, and query Firestore. Upon receiving data, update the store, and `subscribe` to populate the view with `doc` information.

homepage.js

```
const Homepage = ({ docId }) => {

  const [doc, setdoc] = useState(false);

  console.log(docId); // <-- 123

  docStore.subscribe(() => {
    console.log('docStore state changed:', docStore.getState()); // <-- docStore state changed: undefined
    setdoc(docStore.getState());
  })  

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{docId}</div> {/* 123 */}
      <div>{doc.docName}</div> {/* blank */}
    </div>
  );
};
```

reducer.js

```
export default function reducer(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {

    case docTypes.LOAD_DOC_PAGE:
      firebase.firestore().collection("docs")
        .where('docId', '==', action.payload.docId.toLowerCase())
        .get()
        .then(function (data) {

          if (data.docs.length === 1) {
            state = data.docs[0].data();
          }

          console.log('gotten doc', state) // <-- gotten doc data

          return state;
        });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your reducer is very broken.  [**Reducers must *never* make async calls!**](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#reducers-must-not-have-side-effects).  That API call needs to be moved somewhere else entirely, and then you should dispatch an action that will cause the reducer to run and calculate an updated state.

Also, you generally shouldn't subscribe to the store yourself.  Use the React-Redux `connect` and `useSelector` APIs to extract data needed by components from the store state.